# no ahead of time (AOT) code was generated

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, txt

I use Resources.Load read some txt file in Resources subfolders, then I use TinyCsvParser pasrse the content, it works in the editor,when build to iOS, It posts below error, Is there any advice.
Thank you!

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to call method 'System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda::RunVoid2<Country,System.Boolean>' for which no ahead of time (AOT) code was generated.
  at System.Action`2[T1,T2].Invoke (T1 arg1, T2 arg2) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at TinyCsvParser.Mapping.CsvPropertyMapping`2[TEntity,TProperty].TryMapValue (TEntity entity, System.String value) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at TinyCsvParser.Mapping.CsvMapping`1[TEntity].Map (TinyCsvParser.Model.TokenizedRow values) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Func`2[T,TResult].Invoke (T arg) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Linq.Parallel.SelectQueryOperator`2+SelectQueryOperatorEnumerator`1[TInput,TOutput,TKey].MoveNext (TOutput& currentElement, TKey& currentKey) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Linq.Parallel.OrderPreservingPipeliningSpoolingTask`2[TOutput,TKey].SpoolingWork () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTaskBase.Work () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.BaseWork (System.Object unused) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Action`1[T].Invoke (T obj) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ContextCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task& currentTaskSlot) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry (System.Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

unity version: 2019.4

Xcode version: 11.4

Comment: What is the "Path" value and where is your TextAsset placing?

Comment: I am sorry, the file reads data is good , It is a AOT compile error.I will edit the question